# Config servlet in gwt without using web.xml

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, configuration

In normal way, we usually config our servlets in web.xml file for gwt application. However, i have a question that is it possible to config these servlets by code without web.xml or other xml configurations?

For example, i want to config servlets inside the warmup servlet configured in the web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>WarmupServlet</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Servlet 3.0 supports annotation, could able to move those configurations from the web.xml. Suggest you have a look.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other options? Because i am creating a proxy instance for my servlet (exp, an authenticating proxy) for my servlet and i want to bind that instance programmatically to servlet path:

    //create proxy
    MyServlet authenProxyServlet = (MyServlet ) Enhancer.create(MyServlet.class, authenticatingInterceptor);
    
    //Dont know how to bind the proxy servlet to web path here
    

Any idea?

Comment: do you mean you want to check the aithenication before deal with every request? if like this you need create a Filter, rather than a Listener.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at guice and the guice servlet api: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

This is a dependency injection framework where you can bind anything without modifiying the web.xml. The only thing you are going to need is a a start up listener.